If there's no outside space in the universe, is it going to be converged as a dot?
I am a junior high school student in Japan.
Today, while having dinner with my friends, we were talking about the edge of the universe. Then we thought that although it would be exciting to think about how the space outside the universe is going to be, it can be more exhilarating to think about the universe assuming that there's nothing like space outside the universe.
In our hypothesis, the outside surface of the universe would be converged into a dot, 1-dimension, because we assumed there's no "Space", there cannot be any space. Isn't it fascinating? My friends came up with this idea. As soon as I heard that idea, I was electrified.
So, I would like you to share some ideas. Also, I'm so interested in expert and specialized point of view and interpretation.
I'm glad if you give me some ideas!!!

Indeed an exciting thing to think about! Note, as an aside, that a dot would not be 1-dimensional, it would be 0-dimensional.

Btw there is a film titled "Cube" about a group of strangers investigating strange physics inside a cube. Those people were also asking that is the purpose of the cube, how to reach the edge of the cube, and what is outside of it...

This Don Lincoln video might be of interest. Where did the Big Bang happen?. It talks about the origin of the universe and what lies outside the part we can see. Here is another similar one that includes speculation of other universes. What really happened at the Big Bang?

This question is similar to: If the universe is expanding, what is it expanding into?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just a short and very rough summary:
The naïve idea of a border of the universe comes from the idea that in a finite universe if we walk long enough along a straight line, we will reach the border. However, most models that assume a finite universe don't imagine it as a region of space with an "outside". That wouldn't be a finite universe but an infinite universe where only a portion of it is occupied by matter.
What some models of a finite universe postulate is that if you walk long enough in one direction, you may end up returning to the same starting point from another direction. You can compare it with the Earth's surface, which is finite but has no borders, and if you walk long enough, you end at the starting point.
The Earth seems easy to understand because we can imagine it as a 2D spherical surface embedded in 3D space, but it's unclear whether the 3D universe is embedded in something with more dimensions. Therefore, the universe can be finite with no borders while nothing exists outside of it.

Thank you so much for replying, I'm glad to get the insight into the idea of the space!

The “boundary” of the Universe only exists in particular spacetimes, and probably not in ours. In flat spacetime, you can get as distant from any point you want and still never encounter a boundary. In some other curved spacetimes, like with simple global curvature that’s constant-positive or constant-negative, you can end up turning around and not reaching your destination, or reaching your origin again after traveling far enough. Even in more exotic spacetimes (like a toroid, where one of the dimensions is periodic in a particular way), there aren’t boundaries - you might end up back at your origin again, or never see your origin again, but in most cosmologically-valid spacetimes you never hit a hard-stop boundary.
Contrary to popular belief (I’m not going to bother getting a source; as a relativist I get asked plenty of questions from laypeople on the order of “what’s space like outside the Universe”), there isn’t space outside the Universe. Our space is roughly flat, so it extends ad infinitum in all directions, and you can reach any point in space by pointing yourself towards it and flying (avoiding things like planets and stars on the way). For there to be a place that is “outside the Universe”, the Universe would have to be bounded in a way that makes it so that some events in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ (or whatever you want to call the set of events in spacetime) not actually be valid vectors that represent points that “exist”.
As far as we know, such points don’t exist at a cosmological scale. But the closest we can get is points that, in an external coordinate system, are inside a black hole. In spherical coordinates the Schwarzschild metric is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=k_Sc^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{k_S}-r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2-r^2\sin^2 \mathrm{d}\theta\phi^2.$$
Here, $k_S$ is short hand for $1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}=1-\frac{r_s}{r}=1-\frac{v_e^2}{c^2}$, where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius (event horizon radius) of the black hole. Even without very advanced calculus you can tell that this metric behaves badly at $r=r_s$: you end up dividing by zero. That’s a bit of an issue. That surface is the event horizon, which causally disconnects the interior of the black hole from the exterior - observers can see themselves cross the event horizon in a finite amount of proper time, but external spectators will see it take an infinite amount of coordinate time.
The resulting edge of the Universe (if we’re to interpret the Universe as being bounded as the exterior of the sum of all black holes) is that time dilation increases to infinity and spatial contraction - distances appearing to get shorter and shorter on the part of the observer falling in - also goes to infinity. Technically this does result in the loss of the time dimension at the event horizon surface, so you weren’t entirely wrong to think that spacetime gets degenerated into lower dimensions at the boundary. It’s a bit more complicated than the contraction of 3-space into 0-space, but the boundary we’ve defined is as close as we can get to the one you’re thinking about anyways.

Thank you for replying! I'm so excited about the academic interpretation about the space. Thank you so much!!!
